# Android appllication stopping unfortunately

Tags: android, activitynotfoundexception

My app is crashing in an unexpected way. Whenever I run my app's mainactivity, it gets executed. But when I click the button with ID "R.id.msgnow" my app is crashing. I tried all solutions given previously in stackoverflow, verified my manifest.xml and everything seems correct. But still I couldn't figure out what is the cause for crashing. Any suggestion will be really helpful.Thanks

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button now = (Button) findViewById(R.id.msgnow);
       assert now != null;
       now.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               try {
                   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Msg_now.class);
                   startActivity(i);
               } 
               catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add SMS..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

**Msg_now.class**

```
public class Msg_now extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_msg_now);
    EditText cN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_recipients);
    EditText msgContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_content);
    Button find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_contacts);
    assert find != null;
    final String contactName = cN.getText().toString();
    final String messageContent = msgContent.getText().toString();
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.msg_send);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,Contacts.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("mytext",contactName);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    assert send != null;
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(contactName, null, messageContent, null, null);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Msg_now.this, "Recepient or message content missing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

    find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent i = new Intent(Msg_now.this, Contacts.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });

}
```

}

**Contacts.java**

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ContactsFragment fragment = new ContactsFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contacts, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    /*getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.contacts, new ContactsFragment() )
            .commit();*/
}
}
```

**ContactFragment.java**

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

// The column index for the _ID column
private static final int CONTACT_ID_INDEX = 0;
// The column index for the LOOKUP_KEY column
private static final int LOOKUP_KEY_INDEX = 1;

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final String[] PROJECTION =
        {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                        >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME

        };

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final String SELECTION =
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?" :
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";
// Defines a variable for the search string

Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
private String mSearchString = intent.getStringExtra("mytext");
// Defines the array to hold values that replace the ?
private String[] mSelectionArgs = { mSearchString };

private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
};
private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
        android.R.id.text1
};
ListView mContactsList;
// Define variables for the contact the user selects
// The contact's _ID value
long mContactId;
// The contact's LOOKUP_KEY
String mContactKey;
// A content URI for the selected contact
Uri mContactUri;
// An adapter that binds the result Cursor to the ListView
private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
//constructor
public ContactsFragment() {}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the fragment layout
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts,container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity
    mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Gets a CursorAdapter
    mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.contacts,
            null,
            FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS,
            0);
    mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(
        AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long rowID) {
    // Get the Cursor
    Cursor cursor = mCursorAdapter.getCursor();
    // Move to the selected contact
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    // Get the _ID value
    mContactId = Long.valueOf(CONTACT_ID_INDEX);
    // Get the selected LOOKUP KEY
    mContactKey = Integer.toString(LOOKUP_KEY_INDEX);
    // Create the contact's content Uri
    mContactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(mContactId, mContactKey);
    /*
     * You can use mContactUri as the content URI for retrieving
     * the details for a contact.
     */
}

@Override

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    /*
     * Makes search string into pattern and
     * stores it in the selection array
     */
    mSelectionArgs[0] = "%" + mSearchString + "%";
    // Starts the query
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            SELECTION,
            mSelectionArgs,
            null
    );
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    // Put the result Cursor in the adapter for the ListView
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // Delete the reference to the existing Cursor
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}


}




                                                                         ---
```

**My Error**------ beginning of crash

```
11-05 00:39:21.040 2393-2393/com.example.nishant.textontym E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.nishant.textontym, PID: 2393
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nishant.textontym/com.example.nishant.textontym.Msg_now}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.nishant.textontym/com.example.nishant.textontym.ContactsFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.nishant.textontym/com.example.nishant.textontym.ContactsFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                                                                                 at com.example.nishant.textontym.Msg_now.onCreate(Msg_now.java:27)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-05 00:39:26.263 2393-2393/com.example.nishant.textontym I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2393 SIG: 9
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nishant.textontym">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Contacts" />
    <activity android:name=".Msg_now"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.nishant.textontym/com.example.nishant.textontym.ContactsFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: Reading error messages often helps!

Comment: You named your Java class `ContactsFragment`. But you declared `<activity android:name=".Contacts" />`

Comment: It is a fragment of Contacts.class. Is it required to be mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml. Anyways MainActivity.class has an intent to Msg_now.class and not to ContactsFragment.class. Does it matter? Thanks

Comment: @NishantJ the problematic line is not in the code you posted, but here: `com.example.nishant.textontym.Msg_now.onCreate(Msg_now.java:27)`. Again, you can see this in the stack trace.

Comment: Are you trying to show the Fragment by using `startActivity()`?!

Comment: I will call the activity  that contains the fragment using startActivity()

Comment: Anyways. Now I am clear that there is no problem with AndroidManifest.xml. Probably there is some inappropriate use of android functions I guess. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: Can you upload other two classes too. Contacts.java and ContactAdapter.java

Comment: @MohammedAtif Ya. I have uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.nishant.textontym/com.example.nishant.textontym.ContactsFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Your calling `com.example.nishant.textontym.ContactsFragment` activity which was not declared in the manifest or if ContactsFragment is a Fragment then you must add it to an activity, you can't call via intent.

Comment: com.example.nishant.textontym.ContactsFragment is a fragment of activity "contacts.java" and it is mentioned in manifest. But, here I am calling "Msg_now.java" from "MainActivity.java".  But "Msg_now.java" activity is not even opening. Thanks

Comment: Show us msg_no.java class